# How to display an image inline in MUI's Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I need to put a picture and text on one line, the default is to add it on a new line.

```
<MUIRichTextEditor
    label="Type something here..."
    classes={cl}
    defaultValue={content}
    onSave={save}
    onChange={onChange}
/>
```

I can add to the default styles of the root div by adding a flex, but then enter will not work.